# multiple values for argument, can the argument be a multi dimensional array?

Tags: python, function

I want to set an argument as an array. But Typeerror is 'get_vesicle_positions() got multiple values for argument 'coor''. What is the problem? The argument can't be a 2-dimensional array?
This is the function

```
def get_vesicle_positions(self,coor):
        
        peaks=coor
        self.trap_positions = np.array(peaks)
```

what I input is

```
vesicle_detector.get_vesicle_positions(exp_vid[t],coor=cen)
```

where np.shape(cen) is (17,2)

Answer (score 1):

You are giving one positional parameter and and explicit `coor=` parameter, while your method takes only one argument (plus self). Correct `def` could be

```py
def get_vesicle_positions(self, exp_vid, coor):
```

For a mehtod call the first argument `self` is the object the method is called on, so in your case `self` is `vesicle_detector`, `coor` is `cen` and `exp_vid[t]` is the first parameter, which would also be `coor`. That's what python complains about.